# Mysql Query Relations M-M Table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I'm having a small problem making a query in MySQL.
I have the following tables:

- member;
- group;
- member_has_group (this one has the columns id_group referes to the group id and id_member referes to member id)

I'm trying to make a query that gives me the members from a selected group. Can you help me?

I'm not familiar with join tables, but for the search i made i think thats probably one of the solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Elkas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the group id

```
select member.* from member m
  inner join member_has_group mg on m.id = mg.id_member
where mg.id_group = [x]
```

If you only know the group name

```
select member.* from member m
  inner join member_has_group mg on m.id = mg.id_member
  inner join group g on g.id = mg.id_group
where g.name = 'group name'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trival in SQL :

```
SELECT m.id_member, m.name
FROM member AS m
INNER JOIN member_has_group AS h ON (m.id_member=h.id_member)
WHERE (h.id_group=@my_id_group)
```

@my_id_group is the group id you have to give.

Comment: Thanks mate =) you're solution works fine =)
After some thinking it was obvious the answer =(
Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need a join here.

```
SELECT *
FROM `member` 
JOIN `group` ON member.id = group.id
JOIN `member_has_group` ON group.id = member_has_group.id
```

Depending on the information in your tables, you may not need the third table at all.You only need a connector table with you have a "many to many" relationship between then.

> (Ignore the rest if you already know
>   about database normalization)

For example, if you had two tables, Authors and Books. Authors would contain fields such as Name, Publisher, Birthday, whatever is a property of the "author". Books would contain relevant "book" information. This is a "one-to-many" relationship. An author may be linked (via a field such as author_id) to several books, but a book can only have one author. You would not need a third table here.

Building on that, say you had a third table for "Character Names". This would be a list of main character names used in any of the books in the "Books" table. One of the characters happens to be named John Steele. John has a whole series of books written about him. In the Books table, several of the books may list John Steele as a character. While in the characters table, John Steele could be listed in several books. This is "many-to-many". You need a third table here. It would only have two fields. A `book_id` and `character_id`, one entry for each book that John Steele appears in.

[MySql Manual on DB Normalization](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation mate. I was familiar with normalization but not with some query's. But thanks for refreshing my memory =)