# Self m:n Relation

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

I have persons and a person can contact multiple other persons, so basically the "default" tables would be:

```
persons (id)
contacts (person1_id, person2_id)
```

With this schema, I'd have to issue queries like

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     contacts c
WHERE    ( person1_id = *id of person1* AND person2_id = *id of person2* )
         OR
         ( person1_id = *id of person2* AND person2_id = *id of person1* )
```

to get the relation between two persons when I insert such a relation only once.

What is the common practice to deal with this situation?

1. Insert data once and do such an OR query
2. Insert the relation twice so that person1_id = *id of person1* AND person2_id = *id of person2* is enough
3. An entirely different approach?

Assuming:

- The m:n table actually contains additional data, so if I create a relation for both ways, I'd have to duplicate the data
- This is a core part of the application and most non-trivial queries involve at least a sub query that determines whether or not such a relation exists

Comment: Do some reading on undirected graphs in SQL, that's what your `contacts` table is representing.

Comment: make sure that this really matches what you want, meaning that when person1 contacts person2, this means the same thing as person2 contacting person1. That might not be what you really want; I sometimes describe the difference as the twitter "follow" model vs. the facebook "friends" model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your insert logic such that `person1_id < person2_id` is true for all rows, then you can just write

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts c
WHERE person1_id = min(*id_of_person_1*, *id_of_person_2*)
AND person2_id = max(*id_of_person_1*, *id_of_person_2*)
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have to do queries like "all contacts for person1", you'll have to revert to your "OR" query against both sides even if you enforce things like the above recommend (as you wont know if person1 was the min or max of a given relationship)

Comment: +1 for xzilla's remark above: if the question is not "do these two persons have a relationship" but rather "who is related to this person" then the min-max property won't be sufficient.  For the "who is related" query I would probably write it as `...WHERE *id_of_person_1* IN (person1_id, person2_id)` just to make it a bit cleaner and avoid AND/OR precedence issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Join between the tables?

something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM contact c INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = c.person1_id
```

The the where and group bys you need to complete you're query =)

Take a look here how the results will be showed:
http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Regards,
Elkas

Comment: Has the exact same problem. I'd still have to do p.id = c.person1_id OR p.id = c.person2_id etc.

Comment: What about right join or left join? Hummm maybe I'm not understanding well what you want mate.. can you explain it better?

Comment: Given:
Person 1 - id: 1, name: foo
Person 2 - id: 2, name: bar.


When foo contacts bar, it results in an contact entry:
person1_id: 1, person2_id: 2.


When bar wants to contact foo, I have to look in the contact table whether or not it already exists, to do this, I have to issue this query:

select from contacts where person1_id = 1 AND persond2_id = 2 OR person1_id = 2 AND person2_id = 1.

I just want to know what the common practice is for this case, having such an OR doesn't really "feel" right.

Comment: Humm.. ok.. I think this the contants is the relation table right? Try this instead:
SELECT *
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN person p ON p.id= c.person1_id
INNER JOIN contacts c2 ON c2.person2_id = p.id;

Comment: That query won't return anything unless for example foo has a contact with foo (so it contacted itself).

Comment: I think I'm visualizing the problem... imagine this. Contacts is the central table and you can add the person details on the left side of it for the person1_id and in the right side for the person2_id so you can have the full details. I'm just thinking out the query for you. Its late here and I'm in a 16h straight work =( not very focus now. Let think for a while =)

Comment: Just to clarify: My problem is not how to get the data in the first place, my mentioned query does that. It's just about the common way and/or an entirely different approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one mate =)

```
SELECT c.person1_id as id_person_1, c.person2_id as id_person_2, p1.name as name_person_1, p2.name as name_person_2
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN person p1 ON p1.id = c.person1_id
RIGHT JOIN person p2 ON p2.id = c.person2_id;
```

I don't know if it will work.. but give it  try mate =)

Comment: BTW, if i'm not mistaken i had that same problem a few time ago.. get M-N relations data. The difference between you and me is that i had the relation like this member - membre_has_group - group, and you have person - contacts - person. Check the answers they gave me. It helped a lot.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487352/mysql-query-relations-m-m-table

Answer (score 0):

"Insert the relation twice so that person1_id = id of person1 AND person2_id = id of person2 is enough"

That is how I'd do it, personally. It allows to deal with the situation where A has the contact details of B but not the other way around (e.g. a girl gives a guy her number at the bar saying "call me" as she walks out). It also makes the queries simpler.